# git: I got "am/rebase" in my prompt, what to do?

Tags: git

I don't know what I have "touch" but now I have in my prompt this:

`(master|AM/REBASE)`

what should I do?

Answer (score 40):

What you "touched" is the [git am](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am)  command.

Use the following to exit the am mode.

`git am --abort`

Do **not** use git rebase --abort since you will lose all your local changes that are not stashed. It's easy to forget what git rebase --abort really does and lose local changes when you did not intend to get into a rebase state. (I did)

Comment: Also git rebase --abort gives erorred for me `error: could not read '.git/rebase-apply/head-name': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem you should use `git rebase --quit`